# Wix Installer execute Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7, wix3.8

I created already a SQL Installation with my sqlinstalltionCommand using Wix Bootstrapper and I want to pass this exe to my WIX installer as a Prerequisite.

if I opened the SQL Installation it works very fine, but when I call it from WIX Installer it does not work. I know this is not ideal but i need it with my files. Any IDEA??

Answer (score 1):

Running one installer from inside another is not supported. The bootstrapper project can run your prerequisites and your package in one. Do that instead.

Comment: ya but the problem is prerequisites should be installed but sql is optional. so i can not but them in one installation

Comment: You can definitely achieve that using a bootstrapper.

Comment: I have a bootstrapper that lets you choose to install postgres and/or SQL Express or nothing along with the main product.

Comment: That kind of thing was an explicit design goal of Burn. Totally doable.